# MS Powerpoint visible slide borders under large image while editing

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm building a Powerpoint presentation and I'm adding some images with pan animation. So the image I add is larger than the slide, and when I add it, it covers the original slide and I can't see the borders anymore.

I would like to see the slide borders anytime while editing. Not on the presentation itself, but in the editing windows, so i can move the image on the slide and still see the detail I'd like to focus on is inside the slide.

I added the rulers and some pointy guidelines but it is not visible enough. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can press ctrl and roll the mouse wheel in order to unzoom. You should be able to see the entire image.
You can also set the zoom level with the slide on the right bottom corner.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I asked. I want to see a rectangle on the image, where the borders of the slide are.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've misunderstood. A ugly way would be to draw a rectangle just around the slide, and put it on the foreground.

Comment: Ehh, I thought about that, but it would be like the Hulk way of using Office :)

Comment: @Dano - You have been told this answer does not address what the author was asking about.  Feel free to edit it so it does.

Comment: If you're moderately good with VBA, you can write a few simple macros that would have The Hulk do your work for you;  one to add a thin rectangle that matches the slide boundaries on all slides; another to delete all of the added rectangles.  Maybe a third to move all of the rectangles to the top so that newly added items don't hide the rectangles.  Stackoverflow would be the place to get help with this if you decide to have a go at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "Guides". Show guides and then add guides that delimit the slide's borders.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that, and how it answers the question? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rectangle shape on TOP of the picture that is the size of the slide frame. So make the rectangle first, and note the exact position of the rectangle in viewer. Then move it out of the slide temporarily. Then add your picture and make it a little bigger than the slide. Now bring the rectangle to the front and reposition it to the x and y coordinates you noted in the firs step. Now you can resize the picture and delete the rectangle when you're done.

Comment: Actually, x and y will both be 0 -- so that's easy!